# How to read gzipped file from FTP server?

Tags: python, gzip, urllib

I want to read file from public FTP server, and can't seem to figure how to use gzip and urllib efficiently, without explicitely downloading the file then opening it with `gzip.open()`. Is there other way possible at all?

For example "ftp://ftp.server.com/pub/data/archive.gz" is link I got. What is the right way to read the contents from this file in Python?

---

Edit:

So I ended using:

`g = gzip.open(urllib.urlretrieve(url)[0])`

Argument to `gzip.open()` this way is temp file downloaded from url path, and `g` is now like regular file object representing archive contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might work is to read it into memory and then unzip it, the problem is that this will end up using TONS of memory, hence it's better to just download it rather than just dowloading it into memory and manipulating it from there.